# compute an order value for an array of arrays

Tags: functions, algorithms

I am trying to find a solution to the following problem. I am not a mathematicians so my language might need some improvements, but here it is.

I have $n$ groups of numbers. Each Group of numbers contains $k$ **ordered** numbers.

I want to have a function that has the following result.

Given the number of the group $i$ and the value of the item in that group $x_{i}[j]$ ($j$ is unknown) return a value which has same position in the ordered values of the function as the items in the following list:

$x_{1}[1], x_{2}[1] ... x_{n}[1], x_{1}[2], x_{2}[2]... x_{n}[2] .... x_{n}[k]$

$f(1,x_{1,1}),f(2,x_{2,1})... f(n,x_{n,1}), f(1,x_{1,2}), ...$

Restrictions: $n <= 500,  k <= 10000000, x_{i,j} <10000000$

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the fact that you're given $i$ narrows the search down to $\frac{kn}{n}=k$ elements. How about then using the bisection method to find the location of the element?

Comment: I don't want to ( can't ) use the values to do bisection. I want only by using those 2 values to compute a new value that I will use for ordering. And the order presented is: first element in group1, first element in group 2, first element in group3 etc.